# How to avoid repeatedly click a button in a form?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My code:

```
<h:form id="newBSTypePanel" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="newRecod" >
        <h:outputText value="Name"/><h:inputText value="#{treeTableController.newBStypeBean.currentObject.TYPENAME.value}" required="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{treeTableController.saveNewNodes}" oncomplete="Dlg.hide()" update="productDataForm"/>
        <p:commandButton value="close" oncomplete="Dlg.hide()" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

There is quite a bit of functionality associated with the save action. If I click the button repeatedly, it may save a few records in the database. That's not my wish. How can I prevent multiple clicks and resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do double-click prevention in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756426/how-to-do-double-click-prevention-in-jsf)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>`'s Client Side API Widget:

- `PrimeFaces.widget.CommandButton`
- Method Params Return Type Description
- `disable()` - void Disables button
- `enable()` - void Enables button

So you can just use like this:

```html
<p:commandButton widgetVar="saveButton"
                 onclick="saveButton.disable()"
                 value="save"
                 action="#{treeTableController.saveNewNodes}" 
                 oncomplete="saveButton.enable();Dlg.hide()"
                 update="productDataForm"/>
```

Comment: Yes,It really works! Thanks! Before known your answer, I add sth like this**            <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
            <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false">
    <p:graphicImage value="/Resources/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
   </p:dialog>
**  I think these codes may utilize the function of ajax which append with **p:commandButton**

Comment: Not at all.Yeah, your conjecture is very convincing .hehe

Comment: For newer versions of primefaces (lost a few minutes for that):

`<p:commandButton widgetVar="saveButton" onclick="PF('saveButton').disable()" oncomplete="PF('saveButton').enable()"  value....`

Answer (score 11):

For the newer versions of PrimeFaces, the solution would be:

```html
 <p:commandButton widgetVar="saveButton"
                 onclick="PF('saveButton').disable()"
                 value="save"
                 action="#{treeTableController.saveNewNodes}" 
                 oncomplete="PF('saveButton').enable();PF('Dlg').hide()"
                 update="productDataForm"/>
```

Comment: actionListener vs action

Answer (score 3):

Use Javascript and Timer

```
<script>

function disableClick(){
   document.getElementById('saveButton').disables = true;
   setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'saveButton\').disables = false', 5000)"
}
</script>


 <h:form id="newBSTypePanel" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="newRecod" >
        <h:outputText value="Name"/><h:inputText value="#{treeTableController.newBStypeBean.currentObject.TYPENAME.value}" required="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{treeTableController.saveNewNodes}" oncomplete="Dlg.hide()" onclick="disableClick()" id="saveButton" update="productDataForm"/>
        <p:commandButton value="close" oncomplete="Dlg.hide()" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think @RichardDing 's answer is better for me.

Answer (score 3):

As a generic approach you could customize the button renderer, so you can automatically apply a fix to **all** (eligible) buttons in your application.

I use this renderer for a PrimeFaces `p:commandButton`:

```java
public class CommandButtonSingleClickRenderer extends CommandButtonRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodeMarkup(FacesContext context, CommandButton button) throws IOException {
        if (isEligible(button)) {
            final String widgetVar = button.resolveWidgetVar(context);
            final String onClick = getAttributeValue(context, button, "onclick");
            final String onComplete = getAttributeValue(context, button, "oncomplete");
            button.setOnclick(prefix(onClick, getToggleJS(widgetVar, false)));
            button.setOncomplete(prefix(onComplete, getToggleJS(widgetVar, true)));
        }
        super.encodeMarkup(context, button);
    }

    protected boolean isEligible(final CommandButton button) {
        final ActionListener[] listeners = button.getActionListeners();
        return button.isAjax()
                    && button.isRendered()
                    && (button.getActionExpression() != null || (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0))
                    && !button.isDisabled()
                    && !isConfirmation(button);
    }

    protected boolean isConfirmation(final CommandButton button) {
        final String styleClass = button.getStyleClass();
        return styleClass != null && styleClass.contains("ui-confirm");
    }

    protected String getToggleJS(final String widgetVar, final boolean enabled) {
        return String.format("var w=PrimeFaces.widgets['%s'];if(w){w.%sable();};", widgetVar, enabled ? "en" : "dis");
    }

    protected String getAttributeValue(final FacesContext context, final CommandButton button, final String attribute) {
        final ValueExpression ve = button.getValueExpression(attribute);
        if (ve != null) {
            return (String) ve.getValue(context.getELContext());
        }
        String key = attribute + "CommandButtonSingleClickRenderer";
        String value = (String) button.getAttributes().get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            value = (String) button.getAttributes().get(attribute);
            button.getAttributes().put(key, value == null ? Constants.EMPTY_STRING : value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected String prefix(final String base, final String prefix) {
        return base == null ? prefix : prefix + base;
    }

}
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<render-kit>
  <renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.CommandButtonRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.whatever.CommandButtonSingleClickRenderer</renderer-class>
  </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

This renderer was [added](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/pull/95) to PrimeFaces Extensions 8.0. If you are using PFE, you can simply add this renderer to your faces-config.xml `render-kit` section:

```
<renderer>
  <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
  <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.CommandButtonRenderer</renderer-type>
  <renderer-class>org.primefaces.extensions.renderer.CommandButtonSingleClickRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/renderers/commandButtonSingleClick.jsf

Comment: I'd post this as an enhancement in the PrimeFaces issuelist. Very good approach!!!

Comment: @Kukeltje - i posted the link on https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2521 the issue is from 2017. Did you create a new one?

Comment: @no... I'd means I would (if I was the answerer) not I will