# Prevent from multiple clicking button in JSF

Tags: jsf

I want to prevent from multiple clicking button in JSF but every attempt does not work. Action in that button is responsible for loading data to table.
I have something like that:

```
<h:commandButton class="inputButton bFind" action="#{backingBean.load}" value="#{msgc.find}" />
```

but that line allows users to click that button even before action ends.

When I try to do something like that:

```
<a4j:commandButton class="inputButton bFind" onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false" action="#{backingBean.load}" value="#{msgc.find}" />
```

or

```
<a4j:commandButton class="inputButton bFind" onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false" action="#{backingBean.load}" value="#{msgc.find}" />
```

then button is blocked and its prevent from multiple clicking but then I must refresh site to see data in table. :/
I have no idea what i should do to this.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6482443/1391249) (it is for PrimeFaces though).

Comment: First way (with `h:commandButton`) performs a standard submit to the server. The other one ((with `a4j:commandButton`)) performs an ajax request which doesn't render your table by default, unless you specify it in its `reRender` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did it. Thx "@Xtreme Biker" for help. All what I need to do is add reRender attribute:

```
<a4j:commandButton class="inputButton bFind" onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false" action="#{backingBean.load}" reRender="dataTable_#{backingBean.id}" value="#{msgc.find}" />
```

and put content which should be rerendered to

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="dataTable_#{backingBean.id}" ajaxRendered="true">
</a4j:outputPanel>
```