# Action is not getting executed after JS call

Tags: javascript, jsf, action

I'm working on JSF, I'm unable to make action call after JavaScript (JS) execution. 
Without JS action is getting executed as expected.
**What is needed:** Disable the command button until the action (submit) is performed.
Below is the reference piece of code that i'm using.

```
<h:commandButton id = "search" value="Submit" action="#{ManagedBean.retrieve}"           
    onclick="return buttonDisable();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        function buttonDisable() {
            document.getElementById('editForm:search').click();
            document.getElementById('editForm:search').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('editForm:search').style.backgroundColor="#cccccc";
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

Tried many ways but could not find a solution yet. 
Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482443/how-to-avoid-repeatedly-click-a-button-in-a-form

Answer (score 0):

If you change "document.getElementById('editForm:search').disabled = true;" to disabled = false, does that work?

That way after the click it won't be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Justin. Actually the requirement is the buttons should be disabled till the action is completed. Sorry if i was not clear before.

Comment: @Amulya That was not the question... Did you TRY... If so you have way more info on what is the cause of the issue. Please try...

Comment: @Kukeltje, I have tried with disabled=false, But now the button looks like its disabled but i'm still able to perform submit. Am i missing something?

Comment: Dears, I have used below function to set the timeout in JS. This would allow action to execute before disabling the button. Below solution worked for me. 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function buttonDisable() {
   document.getElementById('editForm:search').click();
   setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('editForm:search').disabled = true;
      }, 1000);
   document.getElementById('editForm:search').style.backgroundColor= "#cccccc";
   return true;
  }
</script>